# help on Rpad the online R interface

Tags: r, package

I try to use Rpad

http://code.google.com/p/rpad/

http://rpad.googlecode.com/svn-history/r76/Rpad_homepage/index.html

I have installed it on my machine using install.packages("Rpad")

executing the commands

```
library(Rpad)
Rpad()
```

have launched in my browser the webpage http://127.0.0.1:8079/

I clicked on "New Rpad page"

But this page doesnt seam to be editable (I use chrome as browser)

Any idea to help me on this?

I could not find any tutorial for this package.

Comment: I am not sure that there is an R-related programming question here.

Comment: It is a question about how to use a R package. Is there a better place to ask this question?

Comment: This is not a Chrome issue, the same happens in FF.  I agree with Dirk that this isn't really an R programming question.  But may I suggest you do the following: 1) Follow the links on your browser page to "Rpad documentation" - this contains instructions for setting up your own HTML pages in Rpad. 2) Contact the package owner, but good luck with this, since the project seems rather inactive.

Comment: @Andrie any alternative to suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There hasn't been any maintenance on Rpad for years (the package was last updated in 2007, and the [Rpad website](http://www.rpad.org/Rpad) has been down for almost as long) – I'd be surprised if it worked with any modern browser.  Read the [web interfaces section of the FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#R-Web-Interfaces) for alternatives.

Comment: I notice that Rpad is listed on the FAQ. Do you know who we should contact about errors in the FAQ?